# Powershell, close active window

Tags: windows, powershell, key-bindings

I found a snippet I modified to find the active window and close it via a ps1 script. My goal is to make my key binds the same as Linux using hotkeyD.

I have three issues with the script. One being it does not close the active explorer window if I'm browsing files. How would I make it do so?

The second issue is. I'd like to have winfetch execute in terminal as soon as I launch it. However, if I add it to my powershell profile. It makes the script take longer to execute. How would I make scripts omit code I have in my powershell profile in documents?

Thirdly speed. The script isn't instant. Like pressing alt+F4 would be. It takes a second or two for it to activate. How would I speed it up?

Thanks. Look forward to seeing some replies. Here is the script.

```
[CmdletBinding()]            
Param(            
)            
Add-Type @"
  using System;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  public class UserWindows {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
"@            
try {            
$ActiveHandle = [UserWindows]::GetForegroundWindow()
$Process = Get-Process | ? {$_.MainWindowHandle -eq $activeHandle}
$Process | Select ProcessName, @{Name="AppTitle";Expression= {($_.CloseMainWindow())}}
} catch {            
 Write-Error "Failed to get active Window details. More Info: $_"            
}
exit
```

Comment: [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-open-windows-on-a-computer/) is the answer for your 1-st question. Long execution may be occurred by antivirus system.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Closing Manlwarebytes, its the same amount of time. Question One. The script doesn't close windows filesystem. It'll close everything else, but.

Answer (score 0):

This type of task (i.e. create a Hotkey that closes the active window) looks like a job better suited for [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) than Powershell.

---

For example, this could be done in AutoHotkey with:

```py
#d::WinClose A ;remaps Super+d to a "close the Active Window" command
```

---

If you want more info on how to set up `AHK` or how this script in particular works, feel free to lmk.

Comment: Thanks, but hotkeyD is what I want to use. The issue with AHK is that most of the time. It's detected by games anti cheat. I use my windows computer for gaming.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by `hotkeyD`?

Comment: https://github.com/HikariKnight/hotkeyD

Answer (score 0):

The github project was updated to include a window close function. Emulating the keys alt + F4 it seems.